# Intersections between ts_vector

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

I want to SELECT only records where the intersection of two ts_vector is with zero elements

--PSEUDO-CODE

```
SELECT
 ts_vector('german', query_a) vector_a,
 ts_vector('german', query_b) vector_b
FROM data
WHERE SIZE (vector_a INTERSECT vector_b ) = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Convert them to arrays and then negate the overlap ('&&') operation.

```
WHERE NOT tsvector_to_array(vector_a) && tsvector_to_array(vector_b)
```